# NoReverseMatch at /login/login/signup

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-views

I am trying to create a sign up page using django
after the user press the sign up button i want the page to redirect them to another page using this line of code
`return redirect('congrat')`
and also a function for "congrat" has already been created by me

```
def congrat(request):
    return render(request,"login/congratulation.html")
```

also the url has been defined in the urls.py file
 `path("login/congrat",views.congrat,name = "congrat"),`

[but for some reason this is the output from the website after the button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkLty.png)

I have consulted chatgpt which told me to check my urls.py and check if the function was defined which i have done and i cant seem to find an error there.

the code in the urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [path('',views.home,name = "home"),
           path("sign_up_new/",views.sign_up_new,name = "sign_up_new"),
           path("congrat/",views.congrat,name = "congrat"),
           path("login/log_inn",views.log_inn,name = "log_inn"),
           path("success/",views.success,name = "success"),]
```

Comment: Can you show code in your urls.py file?

Comment: the code in urls.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use as below.

```
return redirect('/login/congrat')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all in how you have the urls wired. I recreated your problem. Please visit https://github.com/ratidzo/login-redirect for the solution. I hope it helps.

Comment: Hay please look at your repo urls.py. It has misspelled congrat.

Comment: thanks for this but yet it is not working

Comment: I was telling about https://github.com/ratidzo/login-redirect  to @Ratidoz G.

Comment: Thanks. Just fixed the misspelled url.